# primefaces show panel when a task completed

Tags: primefaces

I have a button in primefaces, that when is pressed I make some calculations and a new panel should appear showing the results.
I have the code

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit"
        ajax="false" actionListener="#{myBean.search}" oncomplete="panelwv.show();">
    </p:commandButton>

    <p:panel widgetVar="panelwv" visible="false" closable="true"
        toggleable="true">
```

So, when the button is clicked, the MyBean.search method is called, and when is finished I want the panel "panelwv" to appear, but it does not.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oncomplete` can only be executed if `ajax` is `true`. Otherwise the whole page is reloaded. You will probably also want to update the contents of your panel by giving it an id and setting the `update` property of the command button to this id.

Comment: Thanks! do you know how can I add any animation while the myBean.search method executes?

Comment: @loubas don't ask sub-questions in comments. Please post a new question instead.